# LocalStorage in Next.js where the data is only stored once the component is mounted

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, local-storage

So i want certain data to be stored in localStorage. Now the storing data part should only occur when the component is first mounted. Once the component is switched, the data should not be reset to " " values. Below is a part of one of these components. How do I go on about doing so?

```js
'use client'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const FlightInfo = () => {
    const [callsign, setCallsign] = useState("");
    const [from, setFrom] = useState("");
    const [to, setTo] = useState("");

    const dataDictionary: dataDictionaryType = {
        'callsign': callsign.toUpperCase(),
        'from': from.toUpperCase(),
        'to': to.toUpperCase(),
    };

    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem('flightdata');
    if (!storedValue) {
        localStorage.setItem('flightdata', JSON.stringify(dataDictionary));
    }
    console.log(storedValue)

  return (
    ...part of the code...
    <div>
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="CALLSIGN"
            maxLength={7}
            onBlur={(e) =>{setCallsign(e.target.value)}}
            >
        </input>
    </div>
    ...rest of the code...
);
```

Comment: According to the code given, the localStorage will be updated as soon as you changes anything in the state due to re-rendering of the component.

Comment: The value if being set to empty string because the initial values in the states are empty string. So if you need to store the populated values, you need to move the code inside a useEffect with some checks.

Comment: And if you want to store the values just on mount, then in the current code example, it'll always be empty strings due to initial values of the states